# Question on Taylors theorem proving a function is a polynomial if it is n times differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n ∈ N.$ Suppose $f :  \mathbb{R} →  \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely differentiable. Show that if
$f^{(n+1)}(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈  \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is a polynomial function of degree at most
n.

My solution:

By Taylor's Theorem for any $x ∈  \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)x^{2}/2!+...+f^{n}(0)x^{n}/n!+ $ Cauchy
remainder    (**)

Since $f^{n+1}(x)=0$ this implies $f(x)$ must be $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)x^{2}/2!+...+f^{n}(0)x^{n}/n!$

My question:

I don't know if this proves the statement.

In this proof, I have attempted to do it assuming $f$ is a polynomial from the beginning which is my worry as I have essentially assumed the result to prove the result.

f is any function,it is not specified, but I have assumed it is specifically a polynomial, am I not ignoring other cases by assuming the function is of this form and hence losing generality?

Comment: Sure, you can use the remainder in terms of $f^{(n+1)}$ and say it vanishes. Alternatively, use the fact that $g'=0$ implies $g$ is constant (mean-value theorem); use this and induction to arrive at the conclusion. Also, what do you mean by you're assuming $f$ is a polynomial from the beginning? Or you can just think of it as applying the FTC a bunch of times.

Comment: It is my thinking, that we have been told f is some function we can differentiate infinitely and that the n+1th derivative evaluated at any x in its domain is zero. Therefore we are told to discover that f is a polynomial of greatest degree n. f is not specified to be a polynomial, but I have directly said that f is some polynomial of the form ...(as in the question) ignoring f being any other function which is not a polynomial.

Comment: No, what you've done is applied Taylor's theorem. The theorem tells you $f(x)= \text{some polynomial stuff} + \text{some remainder stuff}$. It turns out the remainder is $0$ because of your assumption $f^{(n+1)}=0$. Hence, $f$ equals its $n^{th}$ order Taylor polynomial, i.e $f$ is a polynomial.